# How can add hyphen middle of numbers in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I want seperate number groups with hyphen in angular 8 sign like shown below.

```
1111-2222-3333-4444
```

I use `mat-input` also I want to format setting hyphen when a user start typing number and I want to show 
formatted number in a angular `{{mynumber}}` directive.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Google for "ngx input mask"

Comment: is it work on also mat-input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution I find is a bit ugly.
Basically you'll have to register to the input event of the input and change its value so it contains hyphens. You will also have to peal the hyphens when taking the form values.

So the function for adding hyphens will be something like:

```
export class InputPrefixSuffixExample {
  designedValue: string = "";

  design(inputValue: string) {
    if (inputValue.length > 6) {
      this.designedValue = inputValue.substr(0, 7) + "-" + inputValue.substr(8, 12);
    } else if (inputValue.length > 2) {
      this.designedValue = inputValue.substr(0, 3) + "-" + inputValue.substr(4, 6);
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can use libraries to help you with that. The most popular library is ngx-mask.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask

Answer (score 1):

You can mask with angular material and angular2-text-mask

```js
  datemask = [/\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput [textMask]="{mask: datemask}" [(ngModel)]="myModel" placeholder="Type" value="01/03/2019">
  </mat-form-field>
```

check this Stackblitz for working demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-input-mask-ycbdzl

Comment: This is an external library solution. It requires him to install ngx-mask or alike. Still it is a good solution.